# Minion Pro problem on ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context

**EDIT**: The problem seems to be solved now. (I've had a test with version 2019.02.14 16:57)

---

I am having a rather strange problem using Minion Pro with ConTeXt. The following example breaks at `{\em Gesammelte Schriften}`. There are some lines that I can comment out in order to make the example run, but obviously I really should define the main language. Using the same example with other fonts works just fine. (Note that the font feature definitions were copied from pandoc's context template.)

```
\mainlanguage[de] % comment this line out and it should work with Minion Pro as well

\definefontfeature[default][default][script=latn, protrusion=quality, expansion=quality, itlc=yes, textitalics=yes, onum=yes, pnum=yes] % comment this line out and it should work with Minion Pro as well
\definefontfeature[smallcaps][script=latn, protrusion=quality, expansion=quality, smcp=yes, onum=yes, pnum=yes]
\setupalign[hz,hanging]
\setupitaliccorrection[global, always] % comment this line out and it should work with Minion Pro as well

%\definefontfamily[mainface][rm][Linux Libertine O] % works
%\definefontfamily[mainface][rm][Adobe Garamond Pro] % works
\definefontfamily[mainface][rm][Minion Pro] % breaks at {\em Gesammelte Schriften}

\setupbodyfontenvironment[default][em=italic] % use italic as em, not slanted
\setupbodyfont[mainface,11pt]

\starttext

Adorno, Theodor {\em Gesammelte Schriften}, % comment this line out and it should work with Minion Pro as well

Adorno, Theodor {\em Werke},

Ernst Bloch {\em Werkausgabe},

Karl Marx und Friedrich Engels {\em Werke}

Friedrich Nietzsche {\em Kritische Studienausgabe}
\stoptext
```

Comment: works fine for me. What do you mean by breaking?

Comment: Compilation stops after the problematic line. Error messages: "Tex error" and "attempt to compare number with nil".

Comment: I am on Texlive, by the way...

Comment: I tried with a current context standalone. I would recommend that you use that too - context develops rather fast, and the texlive version is quite outdated.

Comment: Hm, I can actually reproduce.  Here is a slightly more minimal example https://termbin.com/9m1s7

Comment: You can reproduce it on context standalone? As your example suggests this seems to be related to a combination of Minion Pro, italic correction, settings for German, and this particular combination of letters. If you can reproduce this on standalone (?, I will try myself later), could this be related to the version of Minion?

Comment: But, I am not having the same (or a similar) problem on lualatex. I load Minion Pro with fontspec, and I guess on lualatex italic correction is enabled by default, right? (Whereas on context italic correction must be enabled explicitly.)

Comment: @Denis No, italic correction is implemented in Lua in ConTeXt to make it configurable with `\setupitaliccorrection`.  But I agree that it's probably a problem with the font.  Do you also use the one extracted from Adobe Reader?

Comment: @HenriMenke what I meant was: if I don't use \setupitaliccorrection, italic correction will be disabled, whereas on lualatex, it will be activated if I don't disable it. I think this is mentioned in the luaotfload manual says. Is this wrong?

Comment: @HenriMenke I am not sure about the font. Probably it is this version. I have not bought a copy of the font, but I once had InDesign installed so it might also come from there. I honestly don't remember. Can I check this somehow?

Comment: Ok, I have now had a chance to test this with context standalone. -- I can reproduce the problem there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be fixed in the latest beta.

Comment: I can confim that it works now, so closing this question is fine for me.